# How to fix undefined references for inline functions in Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp, r-package

I have been continuously chugging away at building an R package to use in house.  It uses Rcpp and a bunch of functions defined in C++.  I'm getting and error saying there is an undefined reference to two functions.  Both of which are inline functions

I've tried commenting out the functions in the RcppExports, but the code is regenerated every run.  I'm not sure what esle to do.

'''R package Build

```
==> Rcpp::compileAttributes()

* Updated src/RcppExports.cpp
* Updated R/RcppExports.R

==> Rcmd.exe INSTALL --no-multiarch --with-keep.source PHit

* installing to library 'C:/Users/kyle.m.joshi.NAE/Documents/R/win-library/3.6'
* installing *source* package 'PHit' ...
** using staged installation
** libs
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"C:/Users/kyle.m.joshi.NAE/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
make: Warning: File 'RcppExports.o' has modification time 135 s in the future
RcppExports.cpp:317:15: warning: inline function 'double mils2meters(double, double)' used but never defined
 inline double mils2meters(double mils, double range);
               ^
RcppExports.cpp:353:15: warning: inline function 'double sqrtsumsq(double, double)' used but never defined
 inline double sqrtsumsq(double a, double b);
               ^
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++ -shared -s -static-libgcc -o PHit.dll tmp.def Phit.o RcppExports.o hcubature.o pcubature.o -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.0/bin/x64 -lR
RcppExports.o:RcppExports.cpp:(.text+0x2818): undefined reference to `mils2meters(double, double)'
RcppExports.o:RcppExports.cpp:(.text+0x35f8): undefined reference to `sqrtsumsq(double, double)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
no DLL was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'PHit'
* removing 'C:/Users/kyle.m.joshi.NAE/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/PHit'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/kyle.m.joshi.NAE/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/PHit'

Exited with status 1.
```

'''

'''RcppExort.cpp example function

```
inline double mils2meters(double mils, double range);
RcppExport SEXP _PHit_mils2meters(SEXP milsSEXP, SEXP rangeSEXP) {
BEGIN_RCPP
    Rcpp::RObject rcpp_result_gen;
    Rcpp::RNGScope rcpp_rngScope_gen;
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< double >::type mils(milsSEXP);
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< double >::type range(rangeSEXP);
    rcpp_result_gen = Rcpp::wrap(mils2meters(mils, range));
    return rcpp_result_gen;
END_RCPP
}
```

'''

Comment: Your code shows you’ve *declared* the function but it indeed doesn’t show that you’ve *defined* it. My guess is that you defined it *in a different translation unit*. If so, then it’s no wonder that the compiler complains: the whole point of `inline` is that the definition is only available in the current translation unit, not across TU boundaries. — The solution, either way, is to not mark the function as `inline`.

Comment: Seconded as _undefined reference_ almost always indicates a linker error.  You "promised" some code to you application via a signature declaration but didn't deliver.